# How do I change the color of user input text?

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't id.setAttribute work here? I'm just trying to have the color of the text change on a click. https://jsfiddle.net/9fauq8qs/

```
function priority() {
    var id = this.getAttribute('id');
    var todos = get_todos();
    id.setAttribute("style", "color:red");

    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

    show();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Cause `id` is your attribute, not an element. Shouldn't it be `this.setAttribute`?

Comment: the generation of the IDs in the fiddle doesn't work. are you sure this is your only problem?

Comment: Your fiddle reminds me of http://simplechecklist.net/

Comment: Hey, that thing is cool. Cooler than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `priority()` inside the function `this` is `button` element. To change the text color of the p also(assuming that what you meant by user input text ? else remove parentNode) you need its parent via `this.parentNode` (assuming your html structure remains the same).

Also when you call `show()` it replaces the innerHTML of the element with id item, hence removing the color updates. You might want to change that.(i removed it in the fiddle to get this working)

Updated function below:

```
function priority() {
    var todos = get_todos();
    this.parentNode.setAttribute("style", "color: red");
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));
    return false;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9fauq8qs/26/

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why doesn't the color save to localStorage? On adding a new item or on refresh, the red is wiped out.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `setAttribute` on the `id` variable, not on the element.

Assuming (you gave little context :) that `this` is an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object:

```
this.setAttribute('style', 'color: red')
```

Answer (score 0):

There were problems with the `priority()` and `show()` functions. The following should get you closer to what you want to do.

```
function priority() {
  var id = this.getAttribute('value');
  var todos = get_todos();

  localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));
  document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";

  return false;
}
```

```
function show() {
  var todos = get_todos();

  var html = '<p>';
  for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    html += "<p id='item" + i + "'>" + todos[i] + "<button class='remove'>x</button></li><button class='priority' value='item" + i + "'>Priority</button></li>";
  };
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/he7nakL2/